VS Code "Could not find module" in standalone Haskell file
I have a standalone Haskell file I am editing in Visual Studio Code. I'm learning Haskell and simply using ghci to run my code in the integrated terminal.
However, the VS Code editor is complaining that it Could not find module... for one of my import statements (e.g., import System.Random).
Question: If I don't want to create a full project with a dependencies list, what can I do?

You can make a very light-weight cabal-package-alike inline in Haskell source files like this:
{- cabal:
build-depends: base, random
-}
import System.Random

Then you can load ghci by running cabal repl foo.hs (where foo.hs is the name of the file with this content). I'm not sure how to configure VS Code to run cabal repl instead of ghci but perhaps you can poke around and find it yourself now that you know about this feature of cabal. As a bonus, this gives you machine-checkable documentation of what packages you installed along your way to creating your toys.

As an aside, I expected to be able to just run cabal repl --build-depends random foo.hs without this {- cabal: -} block, but that didn't work. Seems like an oversight to me, since cabal repl foo.hs works just fine if there's no --build-depends and no {- cabal: -} block (and no import System.Random, obviously).

If you use cabal install --lib random, it creates a global environment file, which is not ideal.
But you can create a environment file in the current working directory by running cabal install --lib --package-env=. random. This creates a file named .ghc.environment.<platform>-<haskell-version> which includes base, and random by default.
Then you can run ghci <file-name>.
The default packages that comes with ghci are still not accessible. For that you can edit the environment file to include those packages.
For example: If you do import Control.Monad.Writer, it will complain with Failed, no modules loaded.. For that, you need to add mtl-<version> to the environment file which fixes the import.
An example of this would be:
clear-package-db
global-package-db
package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-9.4.8/package.db
package-id base-4.17.2.1
package-id random-1.2.1.2-bcc926197c32f4db989238c5ad865acee4ac5050d11236d68e7af0232def6b43
package-id mtl-2.2.2


This seems to work, says the newbie:

In a terminal, run cabal install --lib random (for example)
In VS Code's Command Palette, run Developer: Reload Window


The cabal install --help says:
If TARGET is a library and --lib (provisional) is used,
it will be added to the global environment.


Note that cabal install --lib pins the versions of libraries it installs, which can cause unhelpful errors like this one in the future where the only solution is to manually edit or completely delete the default environment file.
